# Proper way to inherit an object constructor's prototype?

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, prototype

In the following code, which is the correct way to inherit an object constructor's prototype? I want Admin's prototype to have the 'login' method that was previously attached to the User prototype. I've tried both and I'm not exactly sure which is the correct way.

```
function User(email, name) {
    this.email = email;
    this.name = name;
    this.online = false;
}

User.prototype.login = function() {
    this.online = true;
    console.log(this.email, 'has logged in');
}

function Admin(...args) {
    User.apply(this, args);
    this.role = 'super admin';
}

Admin.prototype = Object.create(User.prototype);  //option 1
Admin.prototype = User.prototype;                 //option 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 is definitely the better approach, because it creates a new object that inherits from but is not the same as `User.prototype`.

Option 2 means that any changes to `Admin.prototype` will be exactly reflected on `User.prototype`, which is not desirable; with that approach, they're the exact same object.

Demo:

```js
function User(email, name) {
    this.email = email;
    this.name = name;
    this.online = false;
}

User.prototype.login = function() {
    this.online = true;
    console.log(this.email, 'has logged in');
}

function Admin(...args) {
    User.apply(this, args);
    this.role = 'super admin';
}

Admin.prototype = User.prototype;                 //option 2

Admin.prototype.getAdminInfo = function() {
  console.log('getting admin info');
}
const user = new User('useremail');
user.getAdminInfo();
```

You should use `Admin.prototype = Object.create(User.prototype);` instead. This way, methods on User become available on Admin, but you'll be able to create separate Admin-only methods as well without changing User.